# Why can’t I find My Dress Up Darling Volume 5+?

Tags: my-dress-up-darling

I recently invested my time into My Dress-Up Darling and I’m absolutely in love with it! However, I want to keep reading the manga in English, but I can’t seem to find physical copies of any volumes after 4.

I found all the way to *roughly* chapter 70 online, but it’s riddled with advertisements and I’d rather just buy a physical copy.

Why can’t I find volumes 5 and beyond for purchase, yet I can find it for free on the web?

Comment: As for the why, most manga are serialized on manga magazines first before being compiled into tankobon, or they are scanlated from Japanese release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Volume 5 is yet to be released in English officially

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Dress-Up_Darling#Volume_list) (as of posting this) Volume 5 isn't due to be released until April 26, 2022 with Volume 6 due to be released August 9, 2022. no date on the other volumes [image: Wikipedia Manga Volume Release]